# Why shutdown a socket can't let the select() return?

Tags: c, sockets, solaris

In my program, there is a thread blocking on a listen socket, which waits for other connections, and the code likes this:

```
{
    ......
    FD_ZERO(&fd_sets);
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &fd_sets);

    ret_val = select(sock_fd + 1, &fd_sets, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (ret_val > 0)
    {
         accept(sock_fd, NULL, NULL);
         ......
    }
    else
    {
        ......
    }
```

Per my understandings, if in other thread, shutdown the socket, and the code likes this:

```
{
    ......
    shutdown(sock_fd, SHUT_RD);
    ......
}
```

I think the select() in the previous thread should return. But after testing, I find the select() is still in blocking.

Why shutdown a socket can't let the select() return?

Comment: You might want to [read this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libmicrohttpd/2011-09/msg00026.html). It seems that Solaris doesn't unblock when you `shutdown` a listening socket.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, after check the return error code of shutdown, it is ENOTCONN (/* Socket is not connected */), so I think I should consider other methods to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You could consider a bit of error handling in your code, instead of just assuming everything works, and throwing away the result of accept(). If you'd done that you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @EJP: OK, thanks for your advice! This code is merely a demo, and I will add error handling in production code.

Comment: No. Add it now. It's there for a purpose. Adding it in production is already too late, as this question proves. You're wasting your own time by deferring this.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, thanks for your sincere advice!